# Python error, 'bool' type not callable

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, boolean

I have a very long code in Python so I can't write it all here. Anyhow, the problem is that I'm plotting a function in the code with the `semilogx` command and everything works fine. However, if I switch to the `plot` command I got this error:

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

What do you think might cause the problem?

It seems that anywhere I use the plot command in the code I get the same error.
I tried plotting the first variable that I use in my code:

```
 f=loadtxt(folder_out+"stars/stars"+str(output)+".txt",skiprows=2)
 ids=f[:,0]
 mass_star=f[:,1] # mass in Msun
 x=f[:,2]
 y=f[:,3]
 z=f[:,4]
 age=f[:,5] # age in Myr

 plot(x,y,'.')
```

And the last line gives me the error. I'm sure I read the variable from the file, they have the same dimension.

Comment: Can you at least paste the line of code that causes the error?

Comment: Post traceback please.

Comment: Do you happen to be using a boolean variable named `str` or `round` somewhere?

Comment: I edited the post, hoping you might have more information. I know how to walk through the code but in this case it's quite hard. That's why I came here hoping that someone might have had the same problem. I don't think it's right giving a vent to anger here!

Comment: What are you doing to get `plot` and `semilogx` available like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error indicates that `plot` is not a function, as you think it is, but a `bool` (ie. `True` or `False`, the result of a boolean expression). This could be for a couple of reasons:

- You explicitly assign a `bool` to a variable named `plot` (perhaps in a loop — remember that loops and `if` statements in Python do not create a new scope)
- You have a bunch of `from whatever import *` statements, one of which imports a name `plot` which is clobbering the one from `pylab` (it might even be a `from whatever import plot` that you haven't noticed)

You could try to narrow it down by a simple text search for `plot` to see if you're doing it explicitly. You could also remove imports and strip down your script until it works as expected, and try to identify the problematic line.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I had a variable named plot. Shame on me.